# Display bug with HTML in a JLabel with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, html, jlabel, gridbaglayout

I have a weird bug with HTML in a `JLabel` and `GridBagLayout` at the top component hierarchy. Here is an short example showing the bug :

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JPanel panelIn = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
panelIn.add(new JLabel("<html># Test</html>"));
panel.add(panelIn);
panel.add(new JButton("Test"));
frame.add(panel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

frame.setSize(100, 100);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

When I run this code, the button is not displayed. However, if I put `<html>Test</html>` instead of `<html># Test</html>`, it works.
Can you explain this bug ?

Comment: When you removed the hash, there was enough room for both components, since one of the components became less in width. Use `GridBagLayout` for all panels and replace the `frame.setSize(100, 100);` with `frame.pack()`.

Comment: Oups... You're right! My real problem was a little bit more complicated but it was indeed a panel size issue... Thanks!